# initialization of two variables at the same time

Tags: c#, variables, if-statement, initialization, shorthand-if

Is there any way to initialize these two variable at the same time?

in this example "time" variable can be "" or has a value.

```
var variable1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(time) ? string.Empty : "value";
var variable2 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(time) ? "value" : string.Empty;
```

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why you need to do this?

Comment: well, when one gets one value, the other gets the other value and vice versa and the condition is the same. so I thought there could be a way to make it shorter.

Comment: Shorter often means less readable. I wouldn't be concerned about shortening 2 lines of code.

Comment: @DavidG Unless there is a large penalty for evaluating the condition.  (Yeah .. I know .. premature optimization)

Comment: If you're concerned about checking the condition twice, you can use simple if statement.

Comment: @PeterM Absolutely, but in that case I'd probably make it longer and use an `if` statement (as suggested by Sriram)

Comment: @DavidG  I probably would too, but I can understand where Mina is coming from.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not possible. But you can create some helper class to hold those two variables. Or you can use some out-of-the-box, like `Tuple`:

```
var variable = string.IsNullOrEmpty(time) ? Tuple.Create(string.Empty, "value") 
                                          : Tuple.Create("value", string.Empty);
```

and then access those two values as `variable.Item1` and `variable.Item2`.

*Note:* Use it **wisely** as variables are in general better because they have *names*, and hence - some *meaning*. Too many `Tuples` with all those `Item1` and `Item2` can fast become unclear, what they are intended for.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go,  a completely unreadable mess:

```
string time = null;

string variable1, variable2 = (variable1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(time) ? string.Empty : "value") == string.Empty ? "value" : string.Empty;
```

In case you couldn't tell, this isn't a serious suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

No. Assuming `"value"` is the same in both cases the most you could do is replace "value" with `variable1` in the second line.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible to initialize multiple variables on a single line of code to the same value:

```
    string variable2;
    var variable1 = variable2 =(string.IsNullOrEmpty(time) ? string.Empty : "value");
```

However, I think this is unreadable and would avoid it.

With what you are trying to do (from your comment), I would use a simple if statement so that the IsNullOrEmpty check is only executed once.

```
    string variable1;
    string variable2;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(time))
    {
        variable1 = null;
        variable2 = "value";
    }
    else
    {
        variable1 = "value";
        variable2 = null;
    }
```

Comment: This is assigning the same value, but that's not what the OP is trying to do.